# pip doesn't respond in the cmd or from venv, it just returns to the directory without error message

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

i installed python3 along with its pip. but pip doesn't respond when called in CMD or from a venv. it just returns back to the directory without giving error message.

i tried to uninstall python and reinstall other versions but the problem persists.

Comment: I Have also added Python to the PATH

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple things that we can try, plus some of these commands can help us pinpoint the issue:

1. This one seems really obvious, but it's happened to me before.  Have you tried closing your command prompt and starting a fresh one?  Sometimes pip doesn't work until I start a new one command prompt session.  Some other times it got to the point where i had to reboot the whole computer first.
2. does anything happen when you type `pip --version`?  If this doesn't display then pip might not be installed correctly.
3. you mentioned that you added python to PATH but did you add pip?

   3.1 Find the dir containing the pip executable, usually the Scripts directory

   3.2 add the path to the Scripts directory to the PATH environment variable.  open up System Properties (type sysdm.cpl in the search or in run, Advanced tab) > Environment Variables > and add the path to the PATH variable

   3.3 again, don't forget to close and reopen your command prompt and try `pip --version` again.

If none of this works try reinstalling python again, making sure to select the option to add Python to the PATH during install.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in a terminal window for these?

```
python --version
```

and

```
pip --version
```

If either doesn't show up, make sure they are set in your PATH environment variables:
[PIP Install Environment](https://www.activestate.com/products/python/pip-tools/pip-install-environment/) and/or [How to add Python to PATH variable in Windows](https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-add-python-to-path-variable-in-windows)

Hope this helps!